# Seperate Working Directory for GDB and Debugged Process

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, working-directory

In the project I am working on, I use gdb to debug - I would like to be able to call `make` from gdb - but I can't because that would mean the working directory would be incorrect. Here is my directory layout and the two options I have tried:

```
Project
 ├─bin
 │ ┗━Option 1
 ├─build
 │ ├─debug.sh
 │ ┟─makefile
 │ ┗━Option 2
 ├─include
 └─src
```

Here is the contents of `debug.sh` using **option 1**

```
#!/bin/bash
gdb --cd=../bin ../bin/ProjectBinary -ex run
```

### Option1:

When I invoke `./debug`, the program runs correctly - the working directory is correctly set to `Project/bin`. But I cannot call `make` from gdb because the makefile isn't in the current directory.

### Option2 (`debug.sh` not shown):

When I invoke `./debug`, the program fails because the working directory is set incorrectly - but I can successfully call `make` from gdb.

How do I get the best of both worlds and allow it so I can call `make` from gdb, as well as the working directory to be correct for the executable - ie how I have 2 working directories, one for the program being debugged, and one for gdb itsself?

Comment: Type `make` inside `gdb` or use its `shell` command, or invoke `gdb` from your `emacs` with  `M-x gdb` or have some `.gdbinit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay in **bin/** but pass the "**-c**" option to **make** so that it switches to **../build** first

```
$ cd ./bin
$ gdb ProjectBinary
(gdb) make -C ../build
```

You can also create `bin/Makefile` that calls the `build/Makefile`:

**bin/Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all
all:
        make -C ../build
```

(Change spaces to tab at the start of the line that calls make)

Then run:

```
$ gdb ProjectBinary
(gdb) make
```

Comment: This answer works thank you, but I was hoping for some way that I don't have to type any paths in. I will first wait for more answers, and if there are no answers which can solve this I will mark this one as the correct answer

Comment: @Ell, I've amended my answer to make that happen ;)